# flutter where is iOS Deployment Target ( inside project runner and inside target runner )?

Tags: flutter, directory, runner

I have a problem with pod install.
I found the solution below:
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/58200

[image]

I found minimumOSVersion
but I cannot find iOS Deployment Targets ( inside project runner, target runner )
no one complains about that answer so.
Obviously, it's my fault that I can't find it

What's wrong with me 
can u find it?
I appreciate it if you screenshot or guide me on how to find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will see `iOS Deployment Targets` in `Xcode`. Here is a screenshot.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your editing and I found it 

Comment: I cannot see this Deployment target dropdown on Xcode